# How to use ternary operator inside component with v-for directive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, conditional-operator

The working code looks as following:

```
<template lang="pug">
b-carousel.d-none.d-sm-block(
  id='categoryRoulette'
  controls
  no-animation
  :interval='0'
)
  b-carousel-slide(
    v-for="category in chunkedArr"
    :key="category.permalink"
  )
    template(v-slot:img)
      b-card-group(deck)
        b-card(
          v-for="(item, index) in category" :key="index"
          :img-src='item.image'
          img-alt='Image'
          img-top
          tag='article'
          style="min-width: 250px;"
        )
          b-card-text.d-flex.justify-content-center.align-items-center
            h5
              a(href="#") {{ item.title }}
</template>
```

But, I need to check if item.image exists and if not to display blank image as following:

```
<template lang="pug">
b-carousel.d-none.d-sm-block(
  id='categoryRoulette'
  controls
  no-animation
  :interval='0'
)
  b-carousel-slide(
    v-for="category in chunkedArr"
    :key="category.permalink"
  )
    template(v-slot:img)
      b-card-group(deck)
        b-card(
          v-for="(item, index) in category" :key="index"
          :img-src='item.image ? item.image : '../assets/images/blank.png''
          img-alt='Image'
          img-top
          tag='article'
          style="min-width: 250px;"
        )
          b-card-text.d-flex.justify-content-center.align-items-center
            h5
              a(href="#") {{ item.title }}
</template>
```

But, this line is not working:

```
:img-src='item.image ? item.image : '../assets/images/blank.png''
```

How to check item.image? Maybe, there is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `'` nested in another `'`, so change it to `"`

```
:img-src='item.image ? item.image : "../assets/images/blank.png"'
```

or

```
:img-src="item.image ? item.image : '../assets/images/blank.png'"
```